# Upload JSF 2.2 : specify the path of files where they will be uploaded

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, file-upload, jsf-2

I'm using Tomcat 7, JSF 2.2, maven
I want to push my web app to a web hosting like this [one](http://jelastic.com/)

In this moment i'm using this path to upload files :

```
  String basePath = "C:" + File.separator + "temp" + File.separator;
    File outputFilePath = new File(basePath+fileName);
//...
```

This way cause me problems like:

1. If someone have not a local disk named "C".
2. In web hosting (in the server) i don't think that it will know the
   path !

So my question is:

**How can i specify the path of files where they will be uploaded ?**

***For example : upload my files in /resources/upload/ or somewhere in the project's folder.***

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Maven Wagon Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) with a protocol the web hoster supports to upload. FTP or SFTP are usually very likely to be supported.

1. I've not seen any web hoster that uses Windows as host OS so far. So you're right that there most probably will not be a C: drive.
2. If the hoster hosts *your* files they will tell you where to put them. So you will know the path.